# Change download dialog default on PHP

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

This is the typical upload code to bring up the dialog box:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

When the popup window comes up, it shows ALL FILES, is there a way to filter this by any way? (by file extension, by file name, by whatever..) BEFORE the user chooses a file?

Cause until now, the only way I know is to wait until the user chooses whatever file he pleases (since all files are showing) just to filter it later and tell him he made a mistake picking the wrong file format.

Comment: No that's the browsers UI

Comment: @Dagon, apparently its obvious for you, I searched all over and couldn't find an answer, that´s why I asked... there was no need to down-vote it :/

Comment: @Dagon Also, that's not true anymore.

Comment: @azirion I dident vote. and if i did you would not know as they are anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP **does not** interact with the user browser in that way, however, you can use **HTML** to preset the extension of the files by specifying it in the html input. Here's an example for images:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" 
   accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

Or even:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" />
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_input_accept.asp).

---

*Note*: The user may still be able to select files other than the ones you specify, so you need to check the extension server side.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks buddy!! :D

Answer (score 2):

[**Yes!**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-accept) This feature was added in HTML5, and is supported in [most modern browsers, with the exception of IE Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept).

You can limit the extensions or MIME types of files that can be selected using the `accept` property. For instance, to only allow the user to upload `.txt` and `.rtf` files:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".txt,.rtf">
```

Or, to only allow images:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very usefull!! :D

Comment: neat, html5 is full of fun stuff